# Is there a way to create site pages and insert webpart into it via PowerShell?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, solution-deployment

We are creating a powershell script to create lists, groups and to install wsp packages.

There are 5 wsp each containing 1 webpart. Is there any way via powershell to create 1 site page and embed 1 webpart on each page?

We have to create new sites pages for every deployment/testing, so feel that it would save lot of time if this was possible via powershell.

I am following [link1](http://meandmysharepoint.blogspot.in/2013/11/add-custom-web-parts-to-page-and.html) and [link2](http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/How-to-Add-WebPart-to-the-Publishing-Page-using-PowerShell-in-SharePoint-2013) but looks like they are referring to publishing pages, I want to make webpart pages..

Comment: Do you want a yes or no answer? If so: Yes ;)

Comment: Hi, I am looking for code for webpart page and them to embed webpart on it. We have worked with publishing pages. But not with webpart pages

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the PowerShell code to create a webpart page:

```
Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell 

$pageTitle = "Page Name"
$layoutTemplate = 4  # Template code
$web = Get-SPWeb http://server/site  
$list = $web.GetList("http://server/site/LibraryName/")
$xml = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?><Method ID=""0,NewWebPage""><SetList Scope=""Request"">" + $list.ID + "</SetList><SetVar Name=""Cmd"">NewWebPage</SetVar><SetVar Name=""ID"">New</SetVar><SetVar Name=""Type"">WebPartPage</SetVar><SetVar Name=""WebPartPageTemplate"">" + $layoutTemplate + "</SetVar><SetVar Name=""Overwrite"">true</SetVar><SetVar Name=""Title"">" + $pageTitle + "</SetVar></Method>"
$result = $web.ProcessBatchData($xml)
$web.Dispose()

# Possible LayoutTemplate values:
# 1 - Full Page, Vertical
# 2 - Header, Footer, 3 Columns
# 3 - Header, Left Column, Body
# 4 - Header, Right Column, Body
# 5 - Header, Footer, 2 Columns, 4 Rows
# 6 - Header, Footer, 4 Columns, Top Row
# 7 - Left Column, Header, Footer, Top Row, 3 Columns
# 8 - Right Column, Header, Footer, Top Row, 3 Columns
```

Source:http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/39c98f27-248c-40b7-b859-088c7dcdeedc/cannot-create-web-part-page-with-powershell?forum=sharepointadminprevious

You can then add the webpart to the webpart page by using the code prsent in one of the posts you mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 2):

```
 $wiki = $web.GetList($web.Url.ToString() + "/SitePages")
  $rootFolder = $wiki.RootFolder;
  $wikipage = $rootFolder.Files.Add($rootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + 
  "/default.aspx", [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPTemplateFileType]::WikiPage)
  $wikiItem = $wikipage.Item;
  $wikiItem[[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBuiltInFieldId]::WikiField] = "";
  $wikiItem.UpdateOverwriteVersion();
  Write-Host 'Wiki page added'
 $defaultPage= $web.GetFile($web.Url +"SitePages/default.aspx") 
 if($defaultPage.Exists -and $defaultPage.ListItem.File.CheckedOutByUser -eq $null)
 {    
     $webpartmanager=$defaultPage.GetLimitedWebPartManager([System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared) 
     $wpGuid = [System.Guid]::NewGuid().ToString()  
     $wpKey = "g_" + $wpGuid.Replace("-","_")   
     $wp =New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ContentEditorWebPart            
     $wp.ID = $wpKey 
     $code = "$"   
     $XmlDoc = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
     $contentXml=$xmlDoc.CreateElement("content")
     $contentXml.InnerText= "<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
                             adipiscing elit </p>"
     $wp.Content =  $contentXml    
     $wp.Title = "Title"  
     $wp.Visible = $webPartProperty_Visible  
     $wp.ChromeType = "Default" 
     $wp.HorizontalAlign = "Center"   
     $webpartmanager.AddWebPart($wp, "Main", 0)   
     $web.Update()
     write-host "webpart added on" $web.Url + $view
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

[I've written a simple script to add a webpart to a page using PowerShell](http://soreddymanjunath.blogspot.in/2014/07/add-webpart-to-page-using-powershell.html) which is tested and working fine.

Please note that to add a webpart to a page export webpart to your local drive and .webpart/.dwp file will be in xml format.

```
cls

asnp "*sh*"

$web=Get-SPweb -Identity "http://SP2013dev.com/sites/addwebpart/"

[xml]$webpartxml= Get-Content -Path "C:\Manju\WPRequest.xml"

$SR = New-Object System.IO.StringReader($webpartxml.OuterXml)

$XTR = New-Object System.Xml.XmlTextReader($SR)

$err=$null

$WebPartZoneID = "Topzone"

$WebPartZoneIndex = 0

 try
   {

  $page=$web.GetFile("Pages/default.aspx");

  $bool=$page.CheckedOutBy

       if($bool)
        {
            Write-Host "Page is already Checkout to " $page.CheckedOutBy.UserLogin

            $page.UndoCheckOut()

            Write-Host "Page is Over ridded by " $web.CurrentUser.DisplayName + " to Add Webpart"
        }

    $page.CheckOut();

    $wmgr=$web.GetLimitedWebPartManager($page,    [System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared);

    $webpart=$wmgr.ImportWebPart($XTR,[ref]$err);

    $wmgr.AddWebPart($webpart,$WebPartZoneID,$WebPartZoneIndex);

    $page.CheckIn('dude');

    $page.Publish('Adding request Site Webpart') 

    "Request Site WebPart SucessfullAdded" + (Get-Date -DisplayHint Date) | Out-File -Append "C:\OutPutLog.txt" 

     $SR.Close();
    $XTR.Close();
     $web.Dispose()

    }
    catch
     {
        $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message 

        "Request Site WebPart Failure" + $ErrorMessage  +  (Get-Date -DisplayHint Date) | Out-File -Append "C:\ErrorLog.txt"
    }
```